# How to use the load file text function in java execute in rectangle class?

Tags: java, string, function, rectangles

I'm trying to write rectangle class and use there the load file text.
we got an example in the point class that was given to us:

```
@Override
public void loadFileText(String data) {
    String[] point = data.split("\\*");
    this.x=Integer.parseInt(point[1]);
    this.y=Integer.parseInt(point[2]);
    this.color=Main.translateColor(point[3]);
    this.fill=Boolean.parseBoolean(point[4]);
```

I would be happy if someone could explain to me what this function does

Comment: The function does not compile.

Comment: Without knowing the rest of the Rectangle class, it seems the intent of this function is to configure the rectangle based on String input.

Answer (score 0):

We are in the same University so I recognize the task.

This function is a part of another function that both of them are working together.
The second function (that You ***didn't*** include in your question) saves to a text file your shape specs and the function you ***did*** mentioned up there,
loading the text and apply the specs to the specific shape.

This one came as a practice of saving and reading from text with a little extra.